# Add multiple affiliate links to Woocommerce Variations with custom button text

Tags: php, wordpress, button, woocommerce, affiliate

I have found this piece of code for functions.php it's getting me partway to where I want to be.

Code I am using found here [Adding affiliate links to Woocommerce variations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40938725/adding-affiliate-links-to-woocommerce-variations)

[Website](https://dev.readandcobooks.co.uk/books/little-men/) with attached code in place

However

1. It is removing my dropdown variation selection & the variable product description and placing all variable product data in a table.
2. I also want to create a second input box in the variation set up to output custom button text for each 'add to basket' - so that I can put the affiliate retailer name.
3. I want to be able to add multiple affiliate retailer buttons (with custom text) per variation, not just one.

What I would like the added multiple affiliate retailer buttons to display per variation dropdown selection, showing below the variable product description and below the variable price.

All help hugely appreciated. I'm not proficient at writing code so will need any advice spelling out for me I am afraid. Thanks.

```
    // Display Fields
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_after_variable_attributes', 'variable_fields', 10, 2 );
//JS to add fields for new variations
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_after_variable_attributes_js', 'variable_fields_js' );
// Save Fields
add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta_variable', 'variable_fields_process', 10, 2 );

function variable_fields( $loop, $variation_data ) {
?>  
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div>
                    <label><?php _e( 'Affiliate URL', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label>
                    <input type="text" size="5" name="my_affiliate_url[<?php echo $loop; ?>]" value="<?php echo $variation_data['_my_affiliate_url'][0]; ?>"/>

            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php
}

function variable_fields_js() {
?>
<tr>
        <td>
            <div>
                    <label><?php _e( 'My Custom Field', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label>
                    <input type="text" size="5" name="my_affiliate_url[' + loop + ']" />
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php
}

function variable_fields_process( $post_id ) {
    if (isset( $_POST['variable_sku'] ) ) :
        $variable_sku = $_POST['variable_sku'];
        $variable_post_id = $_POST['variable_post_id'];
        $variable_custom_field = $_POST['my_affiliate_url'];
        for ( $i = 0; $i < sizeof( $variable_sku ); $i++ ) :
            $variation_id = (int) $variable_post_id[$i];
            if ( isset( $variable_custom_field[$i] ) ) {
                update_post_meta( $variation_id, '_my_affiliate_url', stripslashes( $variable_custom_field[$i] ) );
            }
        endfor;
    endif;
}

//front-end variations
function woocommerce_variable_add_to_cart() {
        global $product, $post;
        $variations = $product->get_available_variations();
        foreach ($variations as $key => $value) {
        ?>
        <form action="<?php echo esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ); ?>"method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
            <input type="hidden" name="variation_id" value="<?php echo $value['variation_id']?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $post->ID ); ?>" />
            <?php
            if(!empty($value['attributes'])){
                foreach ($value['attributes'] as $attr_key => $attr_value) {
                ?>
                <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo $attr_key?>" value="<?php echo $attr_value?>">
                <?php
                }
            }
            ?>
            <table>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <b><?php echo implode('/', $value['attributes']);?></b>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <?php echo $value['price_html'];?>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <a class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt" target="_blank" href="<?php echo get_post_meta($value['variation_id'], '_my_affiliate_url', true); ?>" ><?php echo apply_filters('single_add_to_cart_text', __( 'Add to cart', 'woocommerce' ), $product->product_type); ?></a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </form>
        <?php
        }
}
```

The above code seems to be overriding this script in variation.php

```
defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;

?>
<script type="text/template" id="tmpl-variation-template">
    <div class="woocommerce-variation-description">{{{ data.variation.variation_description }}}</div>
    <div class="woocommerce-variation-price">{{{ data.variation.price_html }}}</div>
    <div class="woocommerce-variation-custom_field">{{{ data.variation.custom_field}}}</div>
    <div class="woocommerce-variation-availability">{{{ data.variation.availability_html }}}</div>
</script>
<script type="text/template" id="tmpl-unavailable-variation-template">
    <p><?php esc_html_e( 'Sorry, this product is unavailable. Please choose a different combination.', 'woocommerce' ); ?></p>
</script>
```